# alert every time send button clicked

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

i want to make an alert modal (from bootstrap5) everytime send button clicked with javascript DOM, but in my case its just can show up the "alert" one time send button clicked, after that it doesn't show up again

The modal's HTML

```
<div class="alert my-alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show d-none" role="alert">
  <strong>Thank you!</strong> We have received your message.
  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
</div>
```

And my Javascript:

```
const scriptURL = 'https://script.google.com/macros/......'
const form = document.forms['portofolio-contact-form']
const myAlert = document.querySelector('.alert')
const btnKirim = document.querySelector('.my-btn')
const btnLoading = document.querySelector('.btn-loading')

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  btnLoading.classList.toggle('d-none')
  btnKirim.classList.toggle('d-none')
  fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form) })
    .then(response => {
      btnLoading.classList.toggle('d-none')
      btnKirim.classList.toggle('d-none')
      myAlert.classList.toggle('d-none')
      form.reset()
      console.log('Success!', response)
    })
   .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
})
```

so every time i click the send button and its success sends to my google sheet, it will show the alert model. However, I can only show this modal one time, after the first time it doesn't show up again until i refresh the page.

Comment: Instead of using `toggle`, you probably want to start by being explicit about what needs to happen: you don't want to rely on what the class list happens to be, you explicitly want to `remove` the `d-none` class on success so that the alert will guaranteed show, and then you want to `add` it when the user clicks the close button so that the alert is guaranteed hidden again.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans ok i tried it and its not work but i noticed there is `data-bs-dismiss` in the close button, and that's the problem, cuz its delete the "alert" when i click the close button(i saw it in inpect)

Answer (score 0):

i've got the answer

"Alert" - HTML

```
<div id="alert" class="alert my-alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show d-none" role="alert">
                    <strong>Thank you!</strong> We have received your message.
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
```

we can see there `data-bs-dismiss` which is mean

> When an alert is dismissed, the element is completely removed from the page structure. If a keyboard user dismisses the alert using the close button, their focus will suddenly be lost and, depending on the browser, reset to the start of the page/document.

so we have to delete this to make the alert not removed when user click the close button
and we have to add an `onclick` atribute with value a function,
like this:

```
<div class="alert my-alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show d-none" role="alert">
                    <strong>Thank you!</strong> We have received your message.
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" onclick="myfunction()" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
```

Javascript

when user click the send button 'd-none' class will remove and after the user click the close button the 'd-none' class will be added

```
const scriptURL = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzAovQklbPcjlV0Z0MAgTrvDR--cWl3mhWyfwcOneOcSbRPBnk_cSTCP2LOcUCiG5/exec'
    const form = document.forms['portofolio-contact-form']
    const myAlert = document.querySelector('.alert')
    const btnKirim = document.querySelector('.my-btn')
    const btnLoading = document.querySelector('.btn-loading')
    
    form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        btnLoading.classList.toggle('d-none')
        btnKirim.classList.toggle('d-none')
        fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form) })
            .then(response => {
                btnLoading.classList.toggle('d-none')
                btnKirim.classList.toggle('d-none')
                // remove the d-none class
                myAlert.classList.remove('d-none')
                form.reset()
                console.log('Success!', response)
            })
            .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
        })
        // add the removed class(d-none)
        function myfunction(){
            myAlert.classList.add('d-none')
        }
```

hope this will help people someday

Comment: Please give [how to give a good answer](/help/how-to-answer) a quick read: don't just paste some code, talk about what went wrong in the question, and why what you're showing fixes that. Instead of showing entire code blocks, just show the parts that had to be changed accompanied by an explanation of why that's necessary to fix things =)